# Android disable lock screen / show when locked

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an android app that can disable the screen when not in use, but can be easily be accessed with out unlocking the phone. The simplest way would be to disable the lock screen I guess. I have tried the disableKeyguard / FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD / FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED, but they all appear to no longer be working. My current thinking is that I will need to keep the app from closing, and simply dim the screen, however, since the use case will have the app in use periodically over several hours, I am really looking to avoid this way of doing it.
Is there any way to create an app that can stay active, but sleep when not in use, without requiring an unlock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` with `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED`. If you need to keep the screen on, use `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`. If you need the app to be running while screen is off, use a wakelock.

Answer (score 0):

My friend dim portion is not going to work you because it will still glow in black room and drain battery.
Why don't you just set the application sleep time to 1 second. And on touching back the screen, it will set back to some maximum number for sleep time.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. could you elaborate on the "application sleep time" ? I'm not sure what you mean.